# Cannot set visible property on Financial Dimensions

Tags: axapta, dimensions, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to limit the Financial Dimensions that a client can see in the Free Text Tax Invoice form in Dynamics AX 2012 R2. I try to personalize the form, however the Financial Dimensions option for Set Visible is blocked out.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the Visible option is blocked out, however if I go to GroupFinancialDimensionLine I can set it visible there.

Problem is I'd like the user to see Financial Dimensions, but limited to the ones I decide.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Default dimension controls are generated dynamically, which may be why you have limited capability in the personalisation form.

I think your problem is best solved by a code change to the generation code.
I have done this myself once involving minor changes:

1. Added a "Visible" field to the `DimensionAttribute` table and form.
2. Tested on the field two places in the generation code.

I don't have access to the source anymore, and I can't remember the exact methods involved.

However this was a global change, not isolated to a specific form, and it may not fit your needs.